# creating pair rdd from two rdds based repetition count of first rdd in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have created 2 Rdd's like below

```
rd2=sc.parallelize([['A', 'B','D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B']])
rd3=sc.parallelize([['A', 'B'],['B', 'C'],['B','D']])
rd2.collect()
[['A', 'B','D'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B']]
rd3.collect()
[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'],['B','D']]
```

Now I want to count the common element in both rdd's repetition count in rd2 as a value in new rd4 i.e.

`['A', 'B']` is common in both rdd's but it is repetition count in rd2 is 2.

my expected rd4 is :

```
[(['A','B'],2),(['B','C'],1),(['B','D'],1)]
```

Comment: If you can use data frame instead of RDD, this would be a sipmle join followed by aggregate count

Comment: ya your correct ,but  as per my requirement i should not use DF's

Answer (score 0):

You can check the repetition count using `countByKey` on rdd, it will return a `defaultdict`.

But you said you want your result as `rdd` so you can use `reduceByKey` function instead.

i'll create the rdd as same as yours

```
rd2=sc.parallelize([['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B']])

rd2.map(lambda x: (tuple(x),1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()
[(('B',), 1), (('A', 'B'), 2), (('B', 'C'), 1)]
```

now you have the output rdd as `(tuple,count)` structure, you can change it to list by a `map` function.

```
rd2.map(lambda x: (tuple(x),1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).map(lambda x: (list(x[0]),x[1])).collect()
[(['B'], 1), (['A', 'B'], 2), (['B', 'C'], 1)]
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: as per my question,  I want to count the common element in both rdd's rd3,rd2.repetition count in rd2 as a value in new rd4 rdd.but as per your code your not considering rd3.above case it will fail.please help me on this. thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is your expected output ? @Sai

Comment: as per my question we should consider  two rdds ,but we are not considering rd3.based on  rd3 elements only ,we should count rd2 elements.please have a look I have updated my question for easy understanding